# c++ problem with public variables and main

Tags: c++

Hello please tell me where is the problem int following code:

```
using namespace std;

class testy{

public:
    static const int velikost = 11;
    char tabulka[velikost][velikost];
    int lastindex = sizeof(tabulka)/velikost + 1;

    int napln(){
        for (int i = lastindex - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            for (int j = lastindex - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                tabulka[i][j] = 'O';
            }
            
        }

    }
    int main(){

        napln();

        //first
        for (int i = 0; i <= lastindex; ++i){

        for (int j= 0; j <= lastindex; ++j)
        {
                if(j == 0 || j == lastindex || i == lastindex/2){
                    tabulka[i][j] = 'x';
                }
                cout << tabulka[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "two" << endl;
        napln();
        //second
        for (int i = 0; i <= lastindex; ++i){

        for (int j= 0; j <= lastindex; ++j)
        {
                if(i == lastindex || j == lastindex/2 && i > lastindex/3 || i == lastindex/3 + 3 && j > lastindex/3 -1 && j < (lastindex/3)*2+1){
                    tabulka[i][j] = 'x';
                }
                cout << tabulka[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "three" << endl;
        napln();
        //third
        for (int i = 0; i <= lastindex; ++i){
            

        for (int j= 0; j <= lastindex; ++j)
        {
                if(j == 0 || j == lastindex || i == j){
                    tabulka[i][j] = 'x';
                }
                cout << tabulka[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "four" << endl;
        napln();
        //four //todo
        for (int i = 0; i <= lastindex; ++i){
            

        for (int j= 0; j <= lastindex; ++j)
        {
                if(i == lastindex/2 && j < 3 ||i == lastindex/2 && j > 8 || j == lastindex/2 && i < 3 ||j == lastindex/2 && i > 8){
                    tabulka[i][j] = 'x';
                }
                cout << tabulka[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "five" << endl;
        napln();
        //five //todo
        for (int i = 0; i <= lastindex; ++i){
            

        for (int j= 0; j <= lastindex; ++j)
        {
                if(j == 0 || j == lastindex || i == j){
                    tabulka[i][j] = 'x';
                }
                cout << tabulka[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "six" << endl;
        napln();
        //six
        for (int i = 0; i <= lastindex; ++i){
            

        for (int j= 0; j <= lastindex; ++j)
        {
                if(i == lastindex/5 || j == lastindex/5 -1 ){
                    tabulka[i][j] = 'x';
                }
                cout << tabulka[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "seven" << endl;
        napln();
        //six
        for (int i = 0; i <= lastindex; ++i){
            

        for (int j= 0; j <= lastindex; ++j)
        {
                if(i == lastindex/5 -1 || j == lastindex/5 -1 || j == lastindex/5 +1 ||i == lastindex/5 +1 ){
                    tabulka[i][j] = 'x';
                }
                cout << tabulka[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "eight" << endl;
        napln();
        //eight // todo
        for (int i = 0; i <= lastindex; ++i){
            

        for (int j= 0; j <= lastindex; ++j)
        {
                if(i == lastindex/5 -1 || j == lastindex/5 -1 || j == lastindex/5 +1 ||i == lastindex/5 +1 ){
                    tabulka[i][j] = 'x';
                }
                cout << tabulka[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        }


    };



};
```

it return this error:

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

i started with c++ latly. I found that should be a problem with main, but i dont know how to fix this thanks.

Comment: Note that both member functions `napln` and `main` are declared to return `int` - but they do not return anything, so your program will have undefined behavior.

Comment: You've written this like a Java program. C++ is not Java, so that sort of thing doesn't work. The entry point for a program in C++ is a function named `main()` that is not a member of any class. If you want to learn C++, focus on learning C++, not on writing as you would in Java and hoping that it works as C++. There are so many differences between C++ and Java (including several instances where code that looks the same behaves differently between them) that trying to use C++ as if it is Java is a waste of time - it's easier to assume you know nothing about C++ and then start learning C++.

Comment: You are also accessing the array out of bounds. Just like in java, C++ arrays start at 0 so in `tabulka[11][11]` you can't access passed `[10][10]`

Comment: I added a few member functions to your class [here](https://godbolt.org/z/YWjW3W) (making one gigantic function to do _everything_ like our `main` is usually not good) and also added some compiler options to make it visible where you do things that aren't allowed. You'll have to scroll down below the warnings to see the program crash.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `int main ()` method is the entry point of the c++ app, this can not be placed inside a class...

you can of course define a method in the class with the same signature, but there is no way that you can start the application from there...

Comment: thanks, but how i can make public variables for main without creating class. For example in java is 
public class test {

    public static int size;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    size = 0;


}

}

Comment: @KryštofHanžl Forget about Java - C++ is a fundamentally different language.

Comment: @molbdnilo i know but is here any way to make this or is this only way over classes ?

Comment: You can call that main method from your global main, if you want that for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

You defined the *member function* `main()`, but not defined any *global function* `main()`, which is used as a program entry point.

You should use `-c` option to have your compiler compiation only (generate object file, but perform no linking to executable).

Another option is defining a global `main()` function to enable your program to compiled as an executable.